Edit HTML of Wordpress Elementor - add custom attribute to image
I'm trying to prevent some images that are above the fold from being lazy loaded but I can't access the html of the images. Only the wrappers.
Is there any way to access plane HTML of Elementor Wordpress?
Thank you

To change the widget content or HTML you can use the Filter Hook elementor/widget/render_content or to add attributes you can try Action Hook elementor/frontend/before_render.

Nice! this seem to be what I was looking for. Can I target specific element in php? For example, I only wanna add lazyload="eager" to specific selector .theme-post-featured-image img

Yes, to add an attribute to img tag of the Image Widget, use elementor/widget/render_content hook. To get the image name use get_name() method

To add a custom attribute to a specific Image Widget`s IMG tag follow the steps given below:
For example, if you are required not to lazy load selected images and want to add the attribute loading="eager" to the IMG tag,
1.  Add the class eager in the Advanced tab of the Edit widget to the Image Widget you do not want to lazy load. Check the screenshot given below:

2.  Add the code given below in the child theme's functions.php file
add_action( 'elementor/widget/render_content', function( $content, $widget ) {
    if ( 'image' === $widget->get_name() ) {
        $settings = $widget->get_settings();
        $classes = $settings['_css_classes'];
        if ( strpos( $classes, 'eager' ) !== false ) {
            $content = str_replace( '<img', '<img loading="eager"', $content );
        }
    }
    return $content;
}, 10, 2 );


Thank you, but this doesn't work. I added the class in elementor advanced settings and added the code to functions.php but there is still loading="lazy" on that image. Is it right, that the class "eager" is being added to the wrapper of img? It's 4 levels up from img

In my case, it is working fine. https://prnt.sc/361r7H9ZiO_L
It would help if you tried to increase the priority value of the action hook in step 2.

I've added 99 priority but still doesn't help. https://prnt.sc/wXefhqBEhv2Q
Maybe I got it nested too deep?

You should check the widget name using the $widget->get_name() line of code. Put this before the if statement echo $widget->get_name();
And see what the name of your widget is. And replace the name of the widget in the if statement. I hope you understand this

It just echoes "html"

You should echo like this https://prnt.sc/EknUeuQqPThm
And the result will be like this, a single character https://prnt.sc/n5coyBVB5PgW

Oh I see, so its this https://prnt.sc/u_jlDUtE5UD2
I added it to the if statement https://prnt.sc/bbXa0RLWAa84 but I still see the image being lazy loaded.
Thank you for your patience with me

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
